# why does it start to swap when there are still plenty of memory?

Tags: memory, centos-7, swap

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         16G        105G         26M        3.3G        107G
Swap:          8.0G        1.9G        6.1G
```

I am running a program to process a big file and this is what I am seeing. I don't understand why it starts to swap a lot when there are still 105G available.

My system is Centos 7

Comment: Does that affect anything?

Comment: What is the swappiness setting? (`cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's 60. What does that mean?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am afraid it's a sign of memory starving.

Comment: Again... does this actually interfere with the operation??

Comment: So far it has been fine, just worrying that it may be dying due to this.

Answer (score 2):

It behaves this way because its programmed to. Decrease VM.swappiness (to 10 or less) and it will use less swap.

The OS believes it is a good idea to move stuff from memory to disk to free up RAM for important stuff (some stuff in memory is virtually never used). Your system recons this file needs to be kept in RAM but is unlikely to be used, so it swaps it out. This is not neccassarily a problem.